# Implement site with text reader

Tags: javascript, plugins, web, html

I have decided to start a new project.

This project is a spell checker to help children and send the report on how well the child is performing to the teacher.

I have already set up where the teacher can place the word, and what I now need to do is that when the pupil clicks the button, the word gets read out loud.

Is there any plugin that I could use?

I'm not worried about how the pupil will access the word but how to make the word be read out.

Any language will be fine.

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: You might want to make a start by looking at the Speech Synthesis API that's part of the HTML5 specification. But keep in mind that I don't know how well it's supported yet by the browsers. More information can be found here: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/01/Web-apps-that-talk---Introduction-to-the-Speech-Synthesis-API#disqus_thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is add the word at the end of the link below, and then you can style it as much as you want e.g. autoplay when you click a button.

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=wordgoeshere" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest thing would be to use html5 audio to play the according word from the webserver whenever it is clicked:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function main() {
      var path = "/sndz"; //folder on the webserver for all your sound files
      var Hello = document.getElementById("Hello");
      Hello.onclick = readWrd(path + "Hello.mp3");
      return false;
    }

    function readWrd(String audioSrc) {
      var wrd = new Audio(audioSrc);
      wrd.play();
    }
  </script>

  <!--and later in make link or sth-->

  <a id="Hello" href="#">Hello</a> 
  <!--leave the 'href' empty if you want the link to be destroyed after you click it-->

</body>

</html>
```